# pandas sort values based other column's value for each row

Tags: pandas, sorting

Generally, I want to sort each ceil of some columns in pandas dataframe based on 1 column's value, That single column stores rank of other columns' value.

Suppose I have a dataframe like this, `chrs` has characters I want to sort, `rank` is the order of charaters for each row :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
from operator import itemgetter
letters = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
np.random.seed(0)
# generate length for each row
data = pd.DataFrame({'col0': np.random.randint(2,10,10)})
# generate random string for each row
data['chrs'] =  data.col0.apply(lambda x: ','.join(np.random.choice(letters) for i in range(x)))
# generate random rank for each row
data['rank_of_chr'] =  data.col0.apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(x,x,replace = False))
data.iloc[:,1:]
```

```
       chrs            rank_of_chr
0   v,s,e,x,g,y [2, 3, 5, 1, 4, 0]
1   y,m,b,g,h,x,o,y,r   [0, 4, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 1, 8]
2   f,z,n,i,j,u,t   [4, 1, 5, 0, 6, 2, 3]
3   q,t [0, 1]
4   f,p,p,a,s   [3, 0, 2, 1, 4]
5   d,y,r,t,t   [1, 4, 2, 0, 3]
6   t,o,h,a,b   [1, 2, 0, 3, 4]
7   j,z,a,k,u,x,d,l,s   [7, 5, 1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 0, 4]
8   x,c,a   [2, 0, 1]
9   a,e,v,f,g   [0, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

I want to sort `chrs` value base on `rank_of_chr` value for each row. For instance, for row 9, I want `a,g,e,v,f`(`a,e,v,f,g` with rank `[0,2,3,4,1]`, rank is ascending just like `rank()` in `sql`).

Since the true data is 50,000,000 rows, I want to find the fastest methods for it.

What I have tried is:

1. use `itertuple` for each rows, use `for` loop to iter over each column I want to sort.
2. for each row, use `np.argsort` to get the index of sorted `chr` and then use `itergetter` to index original value of `chrs`
3. I revise dataframes' value inplace using `dt.at[index,col_name] = new_value`

```
cols_need_sort = ['chrs']
for i in data.itertuples():
    this_order = np.argsort(list(map(int, data.loc[i.Index,'rank_of_chr'])))
    for col_name in cols_need_sort:
        data.at[i.Index, col_name] = itemgetter(*this_order)(data.loc[i.Index,col_name].split(','))
data.iloc[:,1:]
```

Any method to boost performance for this task?